# Where does ICANN publish its list of gTLDs in plain text format?

Tags: dns, domain

ICANN added 100 or so top level gTLDs string in 2013 and 2014. See [Delegated Strings](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/delegated-strings) at ICANN's website.

I want to fetch the delegated strings, but I don't want it with the HTML markup (it complicates my script). I want a simple list of strings like Mozilla publishes for its [Public Suffix List](http://publicsuffix.org/list/effective_tld_names.dat) (sadly, Mozilla's list is only available in HTTP).

Where does ICANN publish its list of gTLDs in plain text format?

(Sorry about the tags. Super User does not have the tags I needed (like ICANN and TLD), so I had to pick some lesser ones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root zone files (plain-text) are at http://www.iana.org/domains/root/files

Comment: Man, that list is almost as painful as HTML, but I think that's as good as its going to get. Thanks.

Comment: Not that hard... save the file as `root.txt` then...
  `grep NS[[:space:]] root.txt | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | sed -e 's/\.$//'`